# CNN Model Training - Resource Exhaustion (Python & Tensorflow)

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am using Microsoft Azure to train a CNN (Convolutional Neural Network) to recognize 11 classes of food using 16k images. The Virtual Machine I'm using is a "STANDARD_NC24_PROMO" with the following specs:
24 vCPUs, 4 GPUs, 224 GB memory, 1440 GB storage.

The problem is that at a simple run of the program I get the following error about Resource Exhaustion:

```
2-conv-256-nodes-0-dense-1576530179
Train on 10636 samples, validate on 2660 samples
Epoch 1/10
   32/10636 [..............................] - ETA: 57:51
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ee913a07a18b> in <module>
     86             model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])
     87             ### TRAIN
---> 88             model.fit(train_images, train_labels,validation_split=0.20, epochs=10,use_multiprocessing=True)
     89 
     90             loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose = 0)

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    518         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    519         # stateless function.
--> 520         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    521     else:
    522       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824 
   1825   @property

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142 
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,256,98,98] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node sequential_7/conv2d_14/Conv2D (defined at /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_distributed_function_7727]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

I will attach below the bit of code that does the training:

```
for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
            NAME="{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer,
                layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))
            print(NAME)

            model = Sequential()

            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size,(3,3),input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)))
            model.add(Activation("relu"))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
            model.add(Dropout(0.5))

            for l in range(conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv2D(layer_size,(3,3)))
                model.add(Activation("relu"))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
                model.add(Dropout(0.5))

            model.add(Flatten())
            for l in range(dense_layer):

                model.add(Dense(layer_size))
                model.add(Activation("relu"))

            #The output layer with 11 neurons
            model.add(Dense(11))
            model.add(Activation("softmax"))


            ### COMPILE MODEL
            model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                                            optimizer="adam",
                                            metrics=["accuracy"])
            ### TRAIN
            model.fit(train_images, train_labels,validation_split=0.20, epochs=10)

            loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose = 0)
            print(acc * 100)
            if maxacc<acc*100:
                maxacc=acc*100
                maxname=NAME
                maxdict[maxacc]=maxname
                print("\n\n",maxacc," ",maxname)
```

My laptop which is nowhere near as good has no problem executing this, yet running it on azure gives me that error. The iteration variables don't matter as I still get the error no matter what their values are.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

I would like to add that the program is not even working with this small amount of layers:

```
dense_layers = [0]
layer_sizes = [32]
conv_layers = [1]
```

Comment: I'm wondering about the load the topography would have. How many dense layers did you want to have in the model? Not sure what your model topography is intended to be but (based on the indentation) it looks like you're running and training 10 epochs x layer_sizes x dense_layers x conv_layers? Is that how it is intended to be?

Comment: @RHP Yes, the indentation in the code snippet is correct. I am not sure about the amount of layers as I would like to have the program find that out on its own, I was starting with `dense_layers = [0, 1, 2]
layer_sizes = [32, 64, 128]
conv_layers = [1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I never used azure for training some kind of networks. But I would try:

- simplify your network and setup, maybe use a powerful single gpu first. Also, figure out what hyperparameter has to change to make it fail after you got it to work with a simpler approach
- reduce the batch size. Most of gpu OOM exceptions are due to too many data that is processed at once.

There is a lot of optimization happening that might cause it to work locally but that works slightly different for multi gpu machines.